# How can I pass search bar results to render on home component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

It's my first time making an app that has a search feature with api and I couldn't find a way to render the search results from the search bar in the header component to home component or any other, so when the user search for something, no matter what's the location the results should render on screen instead of the actual current component's data but for now home screen is fine, since if I find a solution for this, the rest would be easy.
app.js:

```
<Container>
  <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} exact />
  <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={CartScreen} exact />
</Container>
```

header:

```
function Header() {
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
  const [items, setItems] = useState("");
  const debounce = useDebounce(items, 500);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = setTimeout(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/search/?search=${items}`).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data[0]);
      });
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(getData);
  }, [debounce]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className="navCustom">
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>eCommerce</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Form className="d-flex">
            <Form.Control
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              className="me-2"
              aria-label="Search"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setItems(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
          </Form>
```

home:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
//import products from "../../products";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../Product";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../../actions/ProductAction";
import Message from "../Message";
import Loader from "../Loader";

function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center">Latest Products</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {products &&
            products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                {/* <h3>{product.name}</h3> */}
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Are you using a query string?

Comment: Yes using a query string @m4china